# How can i close the visual studio code window with a python command?

Tags: python

i was writing a python script and i got the idea of making a line of code that closes the visual studio code window is there a way to do this with "just" python commands or do you need an other language for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `psutil`

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "Process name to kill" : # You can use some regex here too
        proc.kill()
```

Name of the process can depend on platform you work on but if you list all processes with e.g. `ps -A` (or by printing them with psutil) you should be able to find Visual Studio process name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working on Windows..

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im code.exe")
```